# set property to a class elements in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the below class structure

```
public class elementMap : IelementMap 
    {
       ElementStruct p { get; set; } //this has to be changed. I need to set the properties of ElementStruct here.
       ElementVal E{get;set;}//this has to be changed. I need to set the properties of ElementVal here.

    }


public class elementStruct 
{
  string ID{ get;set; }
  string Name{ get;set; }

}

public class ElementVal 
{
  string ID{ get;set; }
  string Name{ get;set; }

}
```

How I can set property values to elementVal and ElementStruct from the class elementMap?

Comment: Why would you call something `XxxStruct` and make it a `class`?

Answer (score 0):

Assign to private variable

```
public class elementMap 
{
    private ElementStruct p;
    public  ElementStruct P
    {
        set
        {
            p.ID = "id";
            p.Name = "name";
        }
        get {
            return p;
        }
    }
    private  ElementVal e;
    public  ElementVal E { set {
        e.ID = "id";
        e.Name = "name";
    }
        get {
            return e;
        }
    }

}


public class ElementStruct
{
   public string ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class ElementVal
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: It is pointless not to use the implicit `value` parameter in a property setter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're creating an elementMap object like the following:

```
elementMap obj = new elementMap();
```

You have to change both p and E properties to be public so you can access them:

```
public class elementMap : IelementMap 
{
   public ElementStruct p { get; set; } 
   public ElementVal E{get;set;}
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
obj.p = new ElementStruct();
obj.E = new ElementVal();
```

After that, you'll notice that you can't still access this properties own members, that because you also have to set them public:

```
public class elementStruct 
{
  public string ID{ get;set; }
  public string Name{ get;set; }

}

public class ElementVal 
{
  public string ID{ get;set; }
  public string Name{ get;set; }

}
```

Finally, you can now access and set values for them:

```
elementMap obj = new elementMap();

obj.p = new elementStruct();
obj.p.ID = "1";
obj.p.Name= "SampleStruct";

obj.E = new ElementVal();
obj.E.ID = "2";
obj.E.Name= "SampleVal";
```